# place image half inside screen bounds, half outside

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to position an image so that half of it is outside the screen bounds, but I can't figure out how to do it. It is a wheel that I rotate on onFling, if anyone wonders.

Setting alignParentBottom to true and then offsetting the image by half its height in the code is an option, but I would much prefer to do it all in the xml.

Any ideas?

Edit: I've been asked to show my xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you manage to do this? I'm also looking for a solution

Comment: no, even now when I have considerably more experience I can not think of an easy way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs create animation xml with following code:

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toXDelta="-50%p"
android:fromXDelta="-50%p"
 android:toYDelta="50%p"
android:fromYDelta="50%p"
android:duration="1" 
android:fillAfter="true"
>
</translate>
```

create animation in the Activity and use anim above

```
Animation transAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.image_out);
```

strart the animation and image will be half in half out:

```
circleView.startAnimation(transAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give height to image view equal to image size ,add layout margin = -height/2 means layoutmargin will negative of half of image heigth.You can also use the following code.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cv_home_frag_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_200"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_round_rectangle"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/top_sheet_background"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_top_sheet_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```