# Display half of the image at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is to display half of a wheel image at bottom of the screen. I can't cut the image, as I need to rotate it at run time. I have tried different options with relative layout(by setting this as alignParentBottom as true and by giving -ve margin bottom), linear layout(by giving margins). Its working for normal mdpi(320X480), hdpi(480X800) devices. But when device's height increases like for (like 480X870) then the entire wheel is getting displayed.

Wheel Image is

[image: Wheel Image]

and the screen should look like as

[image: Output screen]

Need the help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490517/place-image-half-inside-screen-bounds-half-outside?rq=1

Comment: The post which you have given is related to animation. But my problem is I need to show half wheel image on the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could always crop the piece that you need via the `Bitmap.createBitmap()` static method, and then assign it to the view:

Something like...

```
// Set some constants
private static final Bitmap SOURCE_BITMAP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(....); // Get the source Bitmap using your favorite method :-)
private static final int START_X = 10;
private static final int START_Y = 15;
private static final int WIDTH_PX = 100;
private static final int HEIGHT_PX = 100;

// Crop bitmap
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, START_X, START_Y, WIDTH_PX, HEIGHT_PX, null, false);

// Assign new bitmap to ImageView
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
image.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

In here, your `SOURCE_BITMAP` is your original steering image.

I hope, this helps.

Comment: I can crop the image, but in run time, I need to rotate the image so that pointer will be moved either left or right based on selection of Driver/Rider. If I crop and rotate it, the bottom may be gone while rotating the image.

Comment: See, I did mention that the Bitmap object **SOURCE_BITMAP** will always correspond to the original image **(Complete image)**. So, you will always crop the original image.

Comment: While rotating the image, I need to show that as animation. Its not just like rotate image with some angle and display. If I want show that with animation affect, I can't use the cropped image. If I place the source image at that point, full wheel is coming at bottom of the screen. But I need to display only half of it.

Comment: Ok, I think I am not explaining you clearly. What I meant was **SOURCE_BITMAP** will and always be a complete bitmap image. You will not specify in that object in `protected void onDraw(Canvas c) { }`  but instead Globally. Now, suppose you rotated image say by 2 degree to right, you will take SOURCE_BITMAP data and then crop bottom part, then say again rotated 3 degrees to right, you will take That SOURCE_BITMAP object and crop the bottom part, because that **SOURCE_BITMAP** object is unharmed by your cropping at any instance of time

Answer (score 0):

set android:translationY="300dp" in xml file.

That will move image to bottom side

Answer (score 0):

First set imageview align bottom in relative layout in xml file.
Then set imageview margin programmatically by half (or ratio you want) of imageview height.

```html
int height = imageview.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(0, height/2, 0, 0);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(params);
```