# Show Layout only partially

Tags: android, android-layout

is it possible to show only a part of a Layout/TextView/ImageView without `android:visibility` for individual parts of the layout.
What I want to accomplish is showing for example only the top half of an image and text besides. 
And onClick expand the layout so that the rest of the image and text is visible.
[image]

Comment: can you please post code ?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436863/display-half-of-the-image-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Comment: Post Image to understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't native android options for hiding parts of views.
You can just put another not transparent view over part of your TextView/ImageView using FrameLayout. And onClick will hide this additional view so your TextView/ImageView will fully visible.